# Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route`

Tags: javascript, react-router, reactjs

I'm trying new react-router 1.0.0 and I'm getting strange warnings I can't explain:

> Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `component` supplied to
> `Route`.
>
> Warning: Invalid undefined `component` supplied to `Route`.

**The app is simple:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';

import App from './components/app';

var Speaker = require('./components/speaker');

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        // This is the source of the warning:
        <Route path="speaker" component={ Speaker }/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

**speaker.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';

var Speaker = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
        <h1>Speaker</h1>
    )
  }
});

module.exoprts = Speaker;
```

**app.jsx only has the following render() function:**

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header title={this.state.title} status={this.state.status} />

            {this.props.children}
        </div>);
}
```

When I type in the route to #/speaker or #speaker - nothing is displayed except for title. Please help.

Comment: Is it a typo in your code or question, `module.exoprts`? Also why are you mixing ES6 with ES5? Use imports everywhere instead of doing `require`

Comment: Wow! Just wow! This was it! I spent 50 minutes googling, trying different import styles - ES5 and ES6, but it was a simple typo. Thank you very much @limelights! You're the boss!

Comment: Keeping to one style will reduce these errors in the future, glad it worked!

Comment: I promise I will keep one style going forward :) Would even use "class DaDum" instead of React.createClass({}). Thanks again!

Comment: In my case with ES2015, I simply forgot the export line altogether.

Answer (score 61):

Standardize your module's imports and exports then you won't risk hitting problems with misspelled property names.

`module.exports = Component` should become `export default Component`.

CommonJS uses `module.exports` as a convention, however, this means that you are just working with a regular Javascript object and you are able to set the value of any key you want (whether that's `exports`, `exoprts` or `exprots`). There are no runtime or compile-time checks to tell you that you've messed up.

If you use ES6 (ES2015) syntax instead, then you are working with syntax and keywords. If you accidentally type `exoprt default Component` then it will give you a compile error to let you know.

In your case, you can simplify the Speaker component.

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Speaker</h1>
    )
  }
});
```

Answer (score 23):

it is solved in react-router-dom 4.4.0 see: [Route's proptypes fail](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6420)

now it is beta, or just wait for final release.

```
npm install react-router-dom@4.4.0-beta.6 --save
```

Comment: It's fixed now, in the stable version 5.0.0

Answer (score 23):

I solved this issue by doing this:

instead of

```
<Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
```

do this

```
<Route
 path="/" component={props => <HomePage {...props} />} />
```

Comment: <Route
 path="/" render={props => <HomePage {...props} />} />

Answer (score 20):

In some cases, such as routing with a component that's wrapped with `redux-form`, replacing the `Route` component argument on this JSX element:

```
<Route path="speaker" component={Speaker}/>
```

With the `Route` render argument like the following, will fix issue:

```
<Route path="speaker" render={props => <Speaker {...props} />} />
```

Comment: Such transformation removes warning indeed, but what to do, if the route expects arguments, e.g. trying to transform from  `<Route exact path='/order/:id' component={OrderPage}/>` to `<Route exact path='/order/:id' render={props => <OrderPage {...props} />}/>` breaks down the use of the argument, simply component does not feel the provided value for the :id argument. What to do?

Comment: p.s. I am using React-Router 5.0.1 version, so, that is not the issue. withAlert causes the problem: const OrderPage = withAlert()(withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ConnectedOrderPage))); If I don't wrap the ConnectedOrderPage withAlert, then there is no warning. https://github.com/schiehll/react-alert is the offeding feature.

Comment: @TomR Are `match` objects not accessible from the `OrderPage(props)`?

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a syntax issue, when it happened to me I discovered I typed

`module.export = Component;` instead of `module.exports = Component;`

Answer (score 3):

It's a syntax issue related to imports/exports in your files, mine resolved by removing an extra quote from my import

```
<Route path={`${match.path}/iso-line-number`} component={ISOLineNumber} />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not giving export default then it throws an error.
check if you have given module.exports = Speaker; //spelling mistake here you have written exoprts and check in all the modules whether you have exported correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is an stable release on the `react-router-dom` (v5) with the fix for this issue.

[link to github issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4354#issuecomment-477431190)

Comment: While the fix is about the same warning, I am not sure whether it fixes the issue in this question. Other answers and comments of the original author of the question suggest that here, the cause is a typo. If so, this answer may not be helpful.

Comment: this warning actually arises due to incompatibility issue in between react and react-router-dom.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i leave my **.js** file empty
means i never write anything in my **.js** file after that i was using it in my route 
so make **function component** or **class component** and finally **export** it
will work

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, but for those still arriving here now and using **react-router 4.3** it's a bug and got **fixed in the beta version 4.4.0**. Just upgrade your react-router to version +4.4.0.
Be aware that it's a beta version at this moment.

```
yarn add react-router@next
```

or

```
npm install -s react-router@4.4.0-beta.8
```

Answer (score 0):

react-router@3.2.3 also fixed this bug, just update it:

```
npm i --save react-router@latest
```