# Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop 'component' supplied to 'route'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

When I run the my app on browser I get on my console:

> "Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop 'component'  supplied to
>   'route'"

**My routes file:**

```
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import React from 'react';
import App from './container/App';
import PContainer from './container/PContainer/PContainer';
import PView from './container/PView/PView';

const routes = (
 <Route path="/" component={App} >
  <IndexRoute component={PContainer} />
  <Route path="/Posts View" component={PView} />
 </Route>
);

export default routes;
```

**My PView file:**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class PView extends Component {

 render() {
  return (
    <div>
     <h1>List of Posts</h1>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default connect()(PView);
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?

Comment: are space allowed in route path like ` <Route path="/Posts View" component={PView} />` ??

Comment: yes it is allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop \`component\` supplied to \`Route\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950433/warning-failed-proptype-invalid-prop-component-supplied-to-route)

Comment: @James111 The previous question was due to a typo. I don't see any typo here.

Comment: Are you sure problem comes from PView?, It seems `App` is given to a route too. Is`App` well exported?

Comment: Please post your App and PContainer files also.
Have you rendered the children prop in App.js?
Also, look out for file import errors.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same issue as you.

When I put a connect() component into `<Route />`, this warning must be there. If the component is not a connect() one, then the issue will not be there.

**Solution**

You can change the line

```
<Route path="/Posts View" component={PView} />
```

to

```
<Route path="/Posts View" render={(props) => <PView {...props} />} />
```

then the issue should go away.

**Thinking**

Look at the document of [React-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/basic-components/route-rendering-props)

> component should be used when you have an existing component (either a
>   React.Component or a stateless functional component) that you want to
>   render. render, which takes an inline function, should only be used
>   when you have to **pass in-scope variables to the component** you want to
>   render.

So when you would like to define a route of connect() component, you are implicitly going to pass some additional props into it, then according to the document you should use render instead of component. I guess this is the reason of warning happened.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that App, PContainer, and PView are all valid React components. Check module's imports and exports. Export should be with "default", otherwise you should use named import: `import {somecomp} from './somecomp'`. Check your routes to components.

Your routes look a bit weird: `'./container/PContainer/PContainer'` and `'./container/PView/PView'`.

Maybe it should be `'./container/PContainer'` and `'./container/PView'`, if you don't have **PContainer** and **PView** folders.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have been through this issue. I found that if you have any imported component which is empty or returning nothing then this issue arises because react could not consider it as a valid component.

Have a look if you have any component that you might have left empty.

Comment: Please see [No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it)