# React v15.4 to v16 migration problems

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I'm trying to migrate my whole project and I'm having this issue in the main.jsx file.

- "react-router": "3.0.x"
- "material-ui": "^0.19.4"
- "react-redux": "4.4.8"

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {default}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
>   array instead.
>       in Router (at main.jsx:68)
>       in MuiThemeProvider (at main.jsx:67)
>       in Provider (at main.jsx:66)

**The code**:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(MyRawTheme)}>
            <Router
                history={history}
                routes={routes}
                render={applyRouterMiddleware(useScroll())}
            />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('main-app')
);
```

What is goin on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix everything successfully.

The code was using requires everywhere (even in routes) so I had to change all those requires into `import` or `require('path').default;` since the new webpack creates an object which has the actual required file inside into the key 'default'.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like React Router v3.0.x does not support React 16. Try upgrading to React Router v3.2.x, although I recommend React Router v4. For details see this [thread](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5563).

Looks like you are exporting an Object instead of a `class`. Instead of `const routes` being a React element, make a `Routes` component (function or class) and put all the routes inside its render().
Eg:

```
const Routes = () => (
  <Route>
  .
  .
  .
  </Route>
)
```

and in the main file:

```
<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(MyRawTheme)}>
  <Router
    history={history}
    render={applyRouterMiddleware(useScroll())}>
      {routes}
  </Router>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Comment: I updated to v.3.2.0, which is supposed to be working with React 16, and it shows the same error.

Comment: After commenting a few lines in my routes file, it seems this issue was fixed but now I have "The root route must render a single element" so I'll continue digging.

Comment: Yep but the code is old so it was being "imported" with require so I had two options: add .default at the end or just use standard ES6 import.
I continue the process, it's showing now: "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.". Digging hard!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/eva5E4YC Right now I'm testing with Signin. It's export code -> "export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Signin));"

Comment: Yes, I edited my comment from above with the full export line.

Comment: After changing it to your new edit:
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `routes` supplied to `Router`.
Warning: [react-router] Location "/signin" did not match any routes

Comment: After your last edit:
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Router`.
    in Router (at main.jsx:68)

Comment: I think it is related on how is Webpack importing the classes.
```<Router
                history={history}
                render={applyRouterMiddleware(useScroll())}
            >
                <Route path="/signin" component={Signin}/>
            </Router>```
That is showing the previous error of Element type (...) but got: object.

Comment: You will have to undo changes suggested by me.. `children` seems to be a required prop in v3, as opposed to v4

Comment: and try to standardize all module imports and exports in your project. Might be some syntax mistake. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950433/warning-failed-proptype-invalid-prop-component-supplied-to-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950433/warning-failed-proptype-invalid-prop-component-supplied-to-route)

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway.